# Combine two main loops in one node.js process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to get system notifications and pass them through http to client.

Now I use node.js to provide these two services in one process, but there is a problem.
The notification listener has its own main loop listening to system events, and when the service is started, it makes the server stop providing http service. I think if I could combine main loops of these two services into one, the problem may be solved. Is this possible? And how could I get start?

Thank you,

Here is the sample code:

```
var server = require("express").createServer(),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8000);
server.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("./public/main.html");
});
io.of('/images').on('connection', function (socket) {
    //read images and transfer
}
io.of('/notify').on('connection', function (socket) {
    //start listen system notifications
    notifyLib.start_daemon();
}
```

"notifyLib.start_daemon()" is a native extension and its code is as follows:

```
DBusError error;
int rt;

dbus_error_init (&error);
connection = dbus_bus_get (DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &error);
if (dbus_bus_name_has_owner(connection, DBUS_NAME, &error))
    printf("*** DBUS_NAME had owner\n");
rt = dbus_bus_request_name (connection, DBUS_NAME, 0, &error);
if (!dbus_connection_add_filter (connection, filter_func, NULL, NULL))
    printf("*** Failed to add filter\n");
if (!dbus_connection_register_object_path (connection, DBUS_PATH, &echo_vtable, (void*) 0xdeadbeef))
    printf("*** Failed to register object path\n");
while (dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch (connection, -1))
    ;
dbus_connection_remove_filter (connection, filter_func, NULL);
dbus_connection_unref (connection);
dbus_shutdown ();
```

There are many images to transfer, but when listener starts, image transfer stops.

Comment: I add the sample code in the post.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you mean. Do you do something inside the `/notify` connection handler which blocks the server? If so, you should provide the source code. What you have above looks all right to me.

Comment: Inside the /notify connection handler, notifyLib runs start_daemon(), which is updated in the post. The daemon is a native extension. I think the "while" blocks the server, but don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understand your problem.

The most simple solution is use [Cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

Because it fork several process to handle the request.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use child_process.fork() as a workaround. I guess the while loop, which provides dbus services, in notifyLib.start_daemon() blocks the server. By using child_process.fork(), there are two node processes in the system. What I originally tried to do is integrating this loop into node.js event loop. So only one process is needed while server running.

Answer (score 0):

From node, can you make a timer to call dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch()?

Then you can remove the while() loop.

You'd have to move the dbus clean up code to its own function that node can call when you're done dealing with DBus.

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/